How could the content of pip install and PyPI download be different? is pip broken?
Today I tried to install the latest pymavlink package:
https://pypi.org/project/pymavlink/
pip install pymavlink
Collecting pymavlink
  Using cached pymavlink-2.4.41-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.2 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /home/shared/conda/envs/swarm/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pymavlink) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /home/shared/conda/envs/swarm/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pymavlink) (5.3.0)
Using cached pymavlink-2.4.41-py3-none-any.whl (11.6 MB)
Installing collected packages: pymavlink
Successfully installed pymavlink-2.4.41

after installation I found that the source directory is surprisingly small, it only contains the following files:
/dialects /generator /message_definitions /__pycache__ /CSVReader.py /DFReader.py /fgFDM.py /__init__.py /mavexpression.py /mavextra.py /mavparm.py /mavtestgen.py /mavutil.py /mavwp.py /quaternion.py /rotmat.py /setup.py

But when I download it directly from PyPI, it contains the following files:
/dialects /generator /message_definitions /pymavlink.egg-info /tests /tools /COPYING /CSVReader.py /DFReader.py /fgFDM.py /__init__.py /mavexpression.py /mavextra.py /mavparm.py /mavtestgen.py /mavutil.py /mavwp.py /PKG-INFO /pyproject.toml /quaternion.py /README.md /rotmat.py /setup.cfg /setup.py

the pip version has several directory missing. How could this happen? How to prevent it?
UPDATE 1: fearing that it may be caused by defective publishing, it has also been posted on pymavlink issue tracker:
https://github.com/ArduPilot/pymavlink/issues/969

Means the package build (of that wheel) is broken, not that your tools are. You're doing the right thing by following up with pymavlink's author.

Personally, I use poetry2nix, which when not overridden prefers to use source tarballs rather than wheels. This is good and bad -- sometimes the sources published to pypi are themselves broken and I need to force use of source from github. But that's not a bug in pypi or in pip (or poetry, or poetry2nix, or nix itself...), but rather a bug in the packaging of the individual impacted project. Since packaging failures are a whole class of bugs, though, "How could this happen? How to prevent it?" is too broad to be a single topical Stack Overflow question.

can't be sure yet, will wait for response from tridge

Looking at the two list of files, the differences seem reasonable for the two different types of install.
The "source" install has additional files and directories, but these are to reflect the "source" repository that are not required for end-user installs.

Looking at your git issue you raised, it appears you think you are missing tools/mavgen.py. Looking in the setup.py file, it has instructions to install that file in $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin. And if I look in that directory then I can see the file. The $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin directory gets added to $PATH when the Python Virtual Environment is activated so I did the following test:
(venv) $ mavgen.py -h
usage: mavgen.py [-h] [-o OUTPUT]
                 [--lang {Ada,C,CS,JavaScript,JavaScript_Stable,JavaScript_NextGen,TypeScript,Python2,Python3,Python,Lua,WLua,ObjC,Swift,Java,C++11}]
                 [--wire-protocol {0.9,1.0,2.0}] [--no-validate]
                 [--error-limit ERROR_LIMIT] [--strict-units] [--exit-code]
                 XML [XML ...]

This tool generate implementations from MAVLink message definitions

positional arguments:
  XML                   MAVLink definitions

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
                        output directory.
  --lang {Ada,C,CS,JavaScript,JavaScript_Stable,JavaScript_NextGen,TypeScript,Python2,Python3,Python,Lua,WLua,ObjC,Swift,Java,C++11}
                        language of generated code [default: Python]
  --wire-protocol {0.9,1.0,2.0}
                        MAVLink protocol version. [default: 1.0]
  --no-validate         Do not perform XML validation. Can speed up code
                        generation if XML files are known to be correct.
  --error-limit ERROR_LIMIT
                        maximum number of validation errors to display
  --strict-units        Perform validation of units attributes.
  --exit-code           Return an error code if generation fails.


This all seems to be working as expected.
I would expect your correct command line to be:
mavgen.py --lang="$i" --wire-protocol=2.0 ...

rather than
python -m pymavlink.tools.mavgen --lang="$i" --wire-protocol=2.0 ...


thanks a lot, the command you suggested works, but can it be controlled from the publishing side?

I'm not quite sure what you are asking. The Python packaging tools are pretty flexible and give a lot of control. However, it seems to have been a conscious decision by the developer to do it this way. If you want consistency between "developer" and "user" usage then maybe having developers do an editable install would help.
